# Click event handler for set of buttons with additional argurment

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, telerik

This is my code for creating buttons and attach event to them.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfQuestion; i++)
     {
                Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButton button = new Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadButton();
                // radButton1
                // 
                button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
                button.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold);
                button.Location = new Point(65 * i + 15, 10);
                button.Name = "btn_cauhoi" + (i + 1);
                button.Size = new Size(60, 35);
                button.TabIndex = 1 + i;
                button.Text = "Câu " + (i + 1);

                button.Click += (sender, e) => Button_Click(sender, e, (i + 1));

                // 

                panel_nut_cauhoi.Controls.Add(button);
      }


 private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, int questionIndex)
 {
        MessageBox.Show(questionIndex.ToString());
 }
```

It only show questionIndex = the lastIndex + 1 when i click on every button

Someone help me, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need and cannot pass additional argument to the event handler. To use the index, you can use either of these options:

**Option 1** -  (prefered) Encapsulate the logic which you want to execute on click, in a `DoSomething` method like this `void DoSomething(int index)` and assign event handler to buttons this way:

```
var j = i + 1;
button.Click += (obj, ea) => {DoSomething(j);};
//If for any reason you want to call your `Button_Click`, you can do it this way:
//button.Click += (sender, e) => Button_Click(sender, e, (i + 1));
```

**Option 2** - Set index as `Tag` property of `Button` and then in the event handler cast the sender to `Button` and unbox the index from `Tag` property:

```
var button = (RadButton)sender;
var index = (int) button.Tag;
```

**Option 3** - Store buttons in a `List<RadButton>` and in the event handler find the index of sender in list:

```
var button = (RadButton)sender;
var index = list.IndexOf(button);
```

Comment: I got another problem. Can you help me out ?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311043/button-trigger-event-gotfocus-repeattly