# Button trigger event GotFocus repeattly

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0, telerik

I have created a set of button and attach Click event and GotFocus event to them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfQuestion; i++)
        {
            RadButton button = new RadButton();
            // radButton1
            // 
            button.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
            button.Font = new Font("Segoe UI", 8.25F, FontStyle.Bold);
            button.Location = new Point(65 * i + 15, 10);
            button.Name = "btn_cauhoi" + (i + 1);
            button.Size = new Size(60, 35);
            button.TabIndex = 1 + i;
            button.Text = "Câu " + (i + 1);

            button.Tag = (i + 1);

            button.Click += Button_Click;
            button.GotFocus += Button_Click; ;

            // 

            panel_nut_cauhoi.Controls.Add(button);
        }

   private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var button = (RadButton)sender;
        var index = (int)button.Tag;
        MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
    }
```

It triggers Click event correctly but with GotFocus event it trigger repeatly.

Somebody helps me, please.

Thanks in advances.

Comment: Why are you assigning click handler to gotfocus?

Comment: I want the same work to be handle by those event ! It is not matter

Comment: because its in loop, how many times GotFocus event is triggered? let me guess same as NumberOfQuestion variable? ofcourse yes.

Comment: @toan I don't understand your issue. Gotfocus will be triggered every time the control is in focus. Are you saying that's not the case?

Comment: I would suspect, the button looses focus when the message box is displayed. So each time, the message box closes, the GotFocus event is triggered again. @Mustafa: If the loop is called once when initializing the form, each button gets only one event handler.

Comment: It trigger about 20 times and i don't know why

Answer (score 1):

When you click ok on message box it loose focus and get focus again.
So if you delete MessageBox.Show() you will see its gonna trigger only one time, so you can test code like below, you will see the name of the button as btn_cauhoi1 or btn_cauhoi2 or btn_cauhoi3 up to which button you do click, it means its gonna trigger only one time.

```
        var button = (RadButton)sender;
        var index = (int)button.Tag;
        //MessageBox.Show(index.ToString());
        this.Text = button.Name;
```

Comment: I try that and after that i set the enviroment in debug mode. It still trigger that event repeatedly (about 20 times)

Comment: Dont worry about it, Debugging a focus event is tricky. Because, when you switch between debug mode and exe , the event is triggered again.

Comment: I am not really sure, why you need this event. Maybe using the "Enter" event inszead solves your problem.

Comment: I am making a quiz test. I dynamically create button ( per question) and i want to use Tab, Left Arrow Key and Right Arrow key to change the question. So i need that event